# Views and Taxonomy Terms Page Layout

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a view that sorts by a taxonomy term. After the view layout, i need to find a specific way to have that page that's clicked on to be styled with a different background. For instance, this view will show a background of a Football, but I also have a view for other sports. Is there a way to determine the page name? Right now, its just a node-page-profile.  Here's the link.

http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/profiles-football

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you want to expose your taxonomy to your nodes to change the background.

**Using the Context Module**

> Add a condition Taxonomy and select your term (football) and the
>   reaction Theme HTML add the class (football). As far as I got here you
>   will need one rule for each term, you can't use a token directly.

**Using a custom module**

You can do it with a custom module or just throw a preprocess_page it in your theme:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (module_exists('taxonomy') && $vars['node']->nid) {
    foreach (taxonomy_node_get_terms($vars['node']) as $term) {
      $vars['node_terms'] .= ' taxonomy-'.strtolower(eregi_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '-', $term->name));
    }
  }
}
```

Got from: https://www.drupal.org/node/67587

BTW you should really change the path for the nodes! I know it is still in dev but don't forget it!

Comment: the page-profiles-football is the view page itself. I need to somehow add a style to the pages that are clicked on.

Comment: Give us some specific links so we can see which links your are talking about

Comment: just click on one of the links in the view layout. its a grid layout. click on the athletes name.

Comment: Yeah, you will actually go to each node, not the view itself. Now I got it, you want to expose the taxonomy of the node as a class, right? I will change my answer! You can do it easily with Context module or using a custom module (or even in your theme).

Comment: Ok. so i'm using the context module and i have $term-name in the header. I just need to know how to make it the term name that selected.  take a look. http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/carina-marsh

Comment: Drupal forums I've got this: body class based on taxonomy term can easily be done with the context module. No coding at all:
condition: select the taxonomy term
action: theme html: action class

Comment: What would the action class be for the term?

Comment: I will edit the answer!

Comment: any clue Lauro?

Comment: Add a condition Taxonomy and select your term (football) and the reaction Theme HTML add the class (football). As far as I got here you will need one rule for each term, you can't use a token directly.

Comment: so i think we were thinking the same thing. i have a screenShot of what i did. I added the taxonomy as the context, selected the node type, the taxonomy and then make the theme html the reaction. thanks for your help. how do i post an image here?

Comment: You can't, you need to upload on your server (or anywhere else for that matter)...

Comment: thanks for your help. it really works. you can take a look if you like. Hopefully, this will help others in my situation as well. Once I figured out how it works, it was easy. Well Done ! ! ! !

Answer (score 1):

You can apply different background for different pages using body class which will be unique for each pages. The way you have done right now is correct.

```
body.page-profiles-football .container{background-image:url(''); }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do this , the most easy way is to use the classes name that added to your body tag , so you do in your css

```
.page-node-52 #main-content{
  background: ....
}
```

this classes changes based on the current node ID

Another way you can add image field to node and update the background and in node.tpl file you render that image as background.

also you can add any class to the body array based on page_preprocess in your template.php checkout [Drupal API - template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)